# In SSIS 2008 BIDS write execution log to file

Tags: logging, ssis, bids

I execute a BIDS package using command line (.bat). The package has a script task that successfully writes out a variable to the execution results when executed within BIDS:

> ([The Process is ] Information: VariableName)

I log this process when I execute via batch.

```
dtexec /FILE "\\Server\FilePath\LoadPackage.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING E >%LOGDIR%\%LogFile%
```

That process writes the following:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.0.1600.22
>   for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Started:  2:19:14 PM DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_SUCCESS (0). Started:  2:19:14 PM Finished: 2:19:14 PM Elapsed: 
>   0.532 seconds

I'd like to write out the variable name to the above file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your batch script has requested that dtexec report E, Errors. If you add I (information) to that list, you should capture the missing event

From `dtexec /?`

```
/Rep[orting]        Level[;EventGUIDOrName[;EventGUIDOrName[...]]
                    Level = N or V or any one or more of E, W, I, C, D, or P.
```

Your batch script would then look like 
`dtexec /FILE "\\Server\FilePath\LoadPackage.dtsx" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EI > %LOGDIR%\%LogFile%`

Let me know if that doesn't work.